# Calculate the current date minus 6 months in a DAX measure

Tags: dax

I want to calculate the current date minus 6 months in a DAX measure:

```
MyMeasure = 
DATEADD('Calendar'[Date], -6, MONTH)
```

Returns a table.

In a matrix where 'Calendar' is the calendar table is on the rows, this measure returns an error, because the result of the measure is a table and not a scalar.

How to convert this into a scalar?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
calculate(min('Calendar'[Date]),DATEADD('Calendar'[Date], -6, MONTH))
```